# How to add a string before count and create list using ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to create 10 users and each user is having 5 folder for it.

First i tried to create user like below

```
    - set_fact: 
        user_lists: []
    - name: creating list of users
      set_fact:
        user_lists: "user-{{ user_lists + [ item] }}"
      with_sequence: count=10
```

I am expecting it to users to create like user-1 ,user-2 ..user-10.
but it throws error like below

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type
> error occurred on (user-{{ user_lists + [item] }}): coercing to
> Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}

How to resolve this?

Comment: What structure of the output do you expect?

Comment: @VladimirBotka actually i want a dictionary of users and add 5 folder name under each user. A dictionary of user names under which folders list.

Comment: How are the folders defined? Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VladimirBotka I am trying and framing another question.

Comment: @VladimirBotka As it is a big question , I am trying to resolve as much as possible and raised as another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [with_sequience](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence). For example, the playbook below

```yaml
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        user_lists: []
    - name: creating list of users
      set_fact:
        user_lists: "{{ user_lists + [ 'user-' ~ item ] }}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=10
    - debug:
        var: user_lists
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "user_lists": [
        "user-1",
        "user-2",
        "user-3",
        "user-4",
        "user-5",
        "user-6",
        "user-7",
        "user-8",
        "user-9",
        "user-10"
    ]
```